# How to redirect nginx 404 error_page to homepage?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Here is an example of my server block:

```
  server {
            listen       80;
            server_name website.com;
            root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/website;
             index  index.php index.html index.htm;

 error_page 404 = @homepage;

             location @homepage {
  return 302 /;
}

       location / {
                try_files $uri $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
                   }

            location @extensionless-php {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
           }
            include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

                  include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";
        }
```

What happens is that pages that returned 404 still return 404 error, no redirect happends. What I'm trying to acomplish is to redirect 404 errors to homepage (or at least any other).

Comment: Do you have `fastcgi_intercept_errors` set to `on`? See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_intercept_errors)

Answer (score 1):

My nginx.conf file.

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
        server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            error_page 400 500 404 /;
        }
    }
}
```